# Jenkins task isn't triggered when bitbucket merge

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

environment:
Jenkins 1.650,
Bitbucket plugin 1.1.5,
Git plugin 2.4.2

I have configured my task to be triggered when a change is pushed to my bitbucket repository. All works great when I made same changes (on master) and push it from my computer, but when I create new branch (made some changes), create pull request and merge this branch to master (from web browser) task is not triggered.

Have you same idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the pull-request-merge-button doesn't activate the post-receive hook as a normal push-to-master action does.
You have to use add on such as [external hooks](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.ngs.stash.externalhooks.external-hooks/server/overview) in order to get the same result